# XAMPPのコントールパネルでMySQLのAdminボタンを押すとエラーが表示される。

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

XAMPPのコントールパネルでMySQLのAdminボタンを押すとエラーが表示されます。
「mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]」や「MySQL サーバに接続しようとしましたが拒否されました。config.inc.php のホスト、ユーザ名、パスワードが MySQL サーバの管理者から与えられた情報と一致するか確認してください。」など様々なエラーが出ます。
config.inc.phpを開いてrootユーザーのパスワードを変更して、起動しなおしても、変化はありません。
改善方法があれば教えていただけませんでしょうか。
XAMPPはWindows向けの7.2.12(PHP 7.2.12)をインストールしています。

XAMPP以外でインストールしたMySQLがあるのが原因になるのでしょうか。XAMPPでポート番号3306でstartボタン押すとエラーが出るので3307に変更したりしています。

Comment: XAMPP同梱のMySQLとは別に、MySQL単体でもインストールされているということでしょうか？

Comment: はい。その通りです。単体でもインストールしています。

Comment: 単体でインストールした方のMySQLがサービスとして起動している可能性がありますので、どちらのMySQLが動いているのかを確認してもらい、可能であればMySQL単体の方はいったんアンインストールしてもらった方が状況が整理しやすいかなと思います。